# android studio/firestore - how to add a new FIELD to existing document WITHOUT deleting old data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

How do I add a new field to existing document without deleting old data?

I want to add a new user to the very right section (image attached below) under "users", where orgcode is
"testcode".

What I have so far are:

```
// obj to add
Map<String, Object> userForOrgs = new HashMap<>();
        userForOrgs.put("users", username);

// TODO: add user to /orgs
        mDb.collection("organizations").whereEqualTo("orgcode", _user.getOrgcode())
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc: task.getResult()){
                    doc.getReference().set(userForOrgs);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
```

Firestore structure:

[image: Firestore structure]

Answer (score 1):

To update an existing document, call `update` instead of `set`.

```
for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc: task.getResult()){
    doc.getReference().update(userForOrgs);
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating an existing document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).

Comment: Im a noob so cant vote but Thank you :) Hope you have a great one.